# What are the exit codes used by RASPHONE.exe?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, ras

Due to a major time constraint, need to stick with invoking rasphone.exe from my c program, rather than best approach of using RAS API's. From my code, when the rasphone pop's up a dialler window to the user, if the user click's on cancel button, i have to stop blocking another set of code. 
Ultimately, i need to handle the rasphone returns to control my code flow based on the Success/Failure-Cancel. How to do this? Also, is there any other possibility for silent dialling without any popup?I hope no, as its discussed.

Comment: How are you executing the "rasphone.exe" program?

Comment: I used ShellexecuteEx to call the "rasphone.exe" from my code.

Comment: I want to determine the exit code for rasphone.exe. Then I can use "GetExitProcess" to get the exit code for exe as mentioned in the link you reffered.

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation that lists or even mentions specific exit codes from `RasPhone.exe`. You could just try it and see what code you get back in different circumstances. If it doesn't set the exit code, then you'll have to find another method.

Comment: Yeah I tried by clicking "Dial" and "Cancel" buttons from the RASDIAL window. At both the case I get "0" as exit code. Does RasDial.exe have an exit code?

Comment: Apparently it's 0. As I said, I can't find anything saying it explicitly sets the exit code. (Oh, and please use @Deanna when replying to me so I get the notification)

Comment: @Deanna sure.. And any idea about return value of rasdial.exe?

Comment: No, I don't use either of them. I've only been googling for an answer and breif experimentation.